# remove the qualifier error, when using 'using'

Tags: sql, oracle

my code

```
select distinct student.id
from (student join takes using(id))
        join (instructor join teaches using(id))
        using(course_id, sec_id, semester, year)
where instructor.name = 'Einstein'
```

From the data provided by Oracle,

**I want to obtain the IDs of all students taking Professor Einstein's class.**

but I got an error column part of using clause cannot have qualifier.

How can I fix the code?..

**table sample**

*student*

```
ID      NAME    DEPT_NAME   TOT_CRED
00128   Zhang   Comp. Sci.  102
12345   Shankar Comp. Sci.  32
19991   Brandt  History     80
```

*instructor*

```
ID      NAME        DEPT_NAME   SALARY
10101   Srinivasan  Comp. Sci.  65000
12121   Wu          Finance 90000
15151   Mozart      Music   40000
```

*teaches*

```
ID      COURSE_ID SEC_ID SEMESTER YEAR 
10101   CS-101    1      Fall     2009
10101   CS-315    1      Spring   2010
10101   CS-347    1      Fall     2009
```

*takes*

```
ID      COURSE_ID SEC_ID SEMESTER YEAR  GRADE
00128   CS-101    1      Fall   2009    A
00128   CS-347    1      Fall   2009    A-
12345   CS-101    1      Fall   2009    C
```

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what the structure of the tables are.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle you have to join like below

```
  select distinct st.id
  from student st join takes on st.id =takes.id
   join teaches tch 
   on tks.course_id=tch.course_id
   and tks.sec_id=tch.sec_id 
   and tks.semester=tch.semester 
   and tks.year=tch.year
   join instructor ins on 
   ins.id=tch.id
   where ins.name = 'Einstein'
```

You can also try using like the below  and let me know if its works

```
    select distinct student.id
    from student left join takes using(id)
    left join teaches using(course_id, sec_id, semester, year)
    left join instructor using(id) 
    where instructor.name = 'Einstein'
```

Comment: I add table sample would you check it plz?

Comment: i have modified the query plz check now

Comment: @psaraj12 . . . Can you explain why "you have to use `join`"?  Oracle definitely supports the `using` clause, so the answer is not clear.  (Obviously, the `on` clause works, but it is not clear why the `using` clause does not work.)

Comment: @GordonLinoff the ID of teacher and instructor match and ID of student and Takes match,I have mentioned specific left joins with using as an example